# Retrieve raw pointers of boost intrusive list hook

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class `CNode` that inherits boost `list_base_hook` so that I can use it in a boost intrusive list.

```
class CNode
   //Base hook with default tag, raw pointers and safe_link mode
   :public list_base_hook<>
{
   // Suppose the linked pointers inherited from list_base_hook
   // are "m_prev", "m_next".
};
```

When the node is popped out of the list, it will be pushed into another FIFO. That FIFO plans to reuse `m_prev`, `m_next` to link nodes together while implementing a single-reader-single-writer thread safe semantics.

In my FIFO:

```
class CFIFO
{
public:
  void push_back(CNode *node)
  {
     // Is there any way to update the "m_next"/"m_prev" fields?
     // SetNextLink is faked here..
     m_tail->SetNextLink(node);
     ..
  }
};
```

Is there any way to get the `m_prev`, `m_next` field of `CNode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked fields `prev_` and `next_` are inherited from `list_base_hook` and I can access them directly since they're public in the base.

```
class MyNode: public list_base_hook<>
{
   //..
};

list<MyNode> myList;
for (list<MyNode>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); ++it)
{
   // The type of the pointer is list<MyNode>::node_ptr
   cout << it->prev_ << it->next_ << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iterator_to](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/intrusive/obtaining_iterators_from_values.html) to go from a const reference to an iterator. You can then decrement or increment the iterator. You can actually use `s_iterator_to` with a doubly-linked intrusive list.

**Update**: Oh, you don't want to "get" them, you want to change them. In that case, you'd have to implement your own intrusive container the same way the other intrusive containers are implemented. Personally, I'd just use an intrusive list internally. Making a doubly-linked list act like a FIFO is basically trivial.

Comment: David, I don't see how that iterator helps to link the nodes together in my own FIFO. When a CNode is popped out of boost intrusive list, it'll be pushed into my FIFO. I implement that FIFO myself.

Comment: Oh, you don't want to "get" them, you want to change them. In that case, you'd have to implement your own intrusive container the same way the other intrusive containers are implemented. Personally, I'd just use an intrusive list internally. Making a doubly-linked list act like a FIFO is basically trivial.

Comment: Is boost intrusive list thread-safe(single reader and single writer is enough)? I'm asking because my FIFO could be accessed by a reader and a writer simultaneously.

Comment: You cannot modify the list in one thread while another thread is, or might be, accessing it in any way.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm implementing the FIFO myself. And I cannot relink the nodes popped from boost intrusive list by reusing the fields inherited from list_base_hook?

Comment: Not easily enough that it's worth doing. I would just wrap it on top of `intrusive_list` and use mutexes to protect the FIFO. So long as you hold them only during the quick push/pop operations (and the object is already constructed in the `push` case), the impact of the mutexes on performance is generally beneficial rather than harmful. (Mutexes reduce contention by descheduling contending threads.)

Comment: Oh, synchronization objects are not my options because I'm working on a real-time project which is not so tolerable of the jitters introduced by sync objects. That's another reason why I'm implementing a FIFO myself.. ;)

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'd have to use another linking fields which is kinda redundant, but working..